# text box in table is wider in a strange way

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have a table in a bootstrap-5 web page:

```
<table class="table align-middle table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      <th scope="col">TITLE 1</th>
      <th scope="col">TITLE 2</th>
      <th scope="col">TITLE 3</th>
      <th scope="col">TITLE 4</th>
      <th scope="col">TITLE 5</th>
      <th scope="col">TITLE 6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td><div class="col-12 col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="sum"></div></td>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>boo</td>
      <td>goo</td>
      <td>poo</td>
      <td>zoo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
      <td><div class="col-12 col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="sum"></div></td>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>boo</td>
      <td>goo</td>
      <td>poo</td>
      <td>zoo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td><div class="col-12 col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="sum"></div></td>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>boo</td>
      <td>goo</td>
      <td>poo</td>
      <td>zoo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In small screens it looks good:
[image: mobile]

But in a wider screen there is a strange wide column for the text box:
[image: desktop]
How to fix it, and make the text box column to be same width as the other columns?

Answer (score -1):

Fairly self explanatory, you have a div around that input field that is setting a column size:

```
<td><div class="col-12 col-md-3"><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="sum"></div></td>
```

Simply remove it and the column will scale with the rest of the table:

```
<td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="sum"></td>
```

EDIT:

Something like this would set a fixed width for all table columns:

```
td {
    width: 10%;
}
```

Comment: removing the class causes the text box and the column to be wide. I tried to solve the issue with the classes. Problem is that it does fix the width of the text box but not te width of the column.

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can set a fixed width on each table column using CSS.